# Optimization for SQL Select with Union

Tags: sql, union

I have the following SQL query, in which I make use of UNIONs:

```
SELECT notification FROM NotificationDb notification WHERE notification.proc_name = 'a' AND notification.status = 1 AND notification.module = 1
UNION
SELECT notification FROM NotificationDb notification WHERE notification.proc_name = 'b' AND notification.param1 >0 AND notification.status = 1 AND notification.module = 1
UNION
SELECT notification FROM NotificationDb notification WHERE notification.proc_name = 'b' AND notification.param1 <= 0 AND notification.status = 1 AND notification.module = 1
```

I have it set up this way, because I need them ordered by proc_name field and also param1 value for cases where proc_name is 'b'

QUESTION:  **Is there a better, a more efficient way of putting together a query that would return the same result?**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, there are better ways. Only one SELECT needed. OR the 3 WHERE clauses' conditions. Do you need SELECT DISTINCT or just SELECT?

Comment: The order without an ORDER BY can never be trusted.

Comment: Looks like you can use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need unions here, you can just do a single distinct select:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT notification
FROM NotificationDb
WHERE status = 1 AND module = 1 AND proc_name IN ('a', 'b')
ORDER BY
    proc_name,
    param1 DESC;
```

Here, we add an `ORDER BY` clause which puts `a` `proc_name` records before `b`.  Then, within all `b` records, we show larger `param1` records first.  This sorting maintain the perceived ordering you have in current union query (though it should be noted that no such actual order is there; *always* use an `ORDER BY` clause if you expect a certain sorting in your result set).

Comment: This should fail because `proc_name` is not defined due to the `distinct`.  I am also baffled at this being accepted, because the logic does not look the same as the code in the question.  Perhaps something changed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Now I'm also wondering what the OP's database is (perhaps something like MySQL which allows it to run).